# Sentry JVM option placeholder

Tags: java, sentry

I'm configuring Sentry to use with our projects but have some issue with it. I would like to put some placeholders in configuration file like

```
extra=prj:${project.name}
```

Where `project.name` is a JVM option set like this:

```
java -Dproject.name pname -jar my.jar
```

Is there a way to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the Sentry Java SDK options can be provided as Java System Properties or System Environment Variables already. If you want to use either of those I would just skip using the `sentry.properties` file altogether: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/#configuration-via-the-runtime-environment

For example:

```
java -Dsentry.extra=prj:pname -jar my.jar
```

All you need to do is prefix the option name with `sentry.` when you provide the property on the commandline.